# Can Anyone explain how to identify the match text in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

*Assume that newFile[0] = 'Dany' and prsntFile[0] = 'Dany'. If newFile equal to present file then alert will work.* My question is some time prsntFile[0] = 'Dany - 1' and my newFile[0] = 'Dany' but for this also i want to trigger the alert function.

prsntFile[0] may also contain dany -2 or dany -3. for this also i want to alert 'match'. any solution guys*

```
var newFile = 'Dany';
$(".copyDoc").each(function(){
    var existFiles = this.value;
    var prsntFile = existFiles.split('.');
    if(newFile[0] == prsntFile[0]){
        alert('match');
    }elseif(newFile[0] == prsntFile[0]){

    }
    //alert(newFile[0]);
});
```

My Input hidden field

```
<input class="copyDoc" name="copyDoc[]" value="Dany - 1" type="hidden">
```

Comment: Above code is checking if the file names are starting by same letter.

Comment: yeah thats what i need, To show my code less I make some alteration in my code.

Comment: is there any other condition other than  "-" like e.g "Dany + 1" ? 
You can just use "split" and trim() and take the first element to compare with the existing value .

Comment: try `var regex = /^fileNameInitials/i; if(regex.test(prsntFile)) { alert('...') } else { ...}`

Comment: No there is no cndition to make Dany +1, It always have dany - 1 to dany - 9

Comment: can you please post as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, regex to do it.

```js
var a = 'Dany'
var b = 'Dany 2'
var c = 'Day2'
var d = 'Dany-2'

var patt = new RegExp("^"+a+"");
console.log(patt.test(b));
console.log(patt.test(c));
console.log(patt.test(d));
```

The test() method tests for a match in a string.

This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.

So, I have created a regular expression object, `patt` and used that with test to find if there is a match in the string.

In regex : `^n   Matches any string with n at the beginning of it`

Comment: can you please explain the use of test, I cant understand that

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: to know more about test() method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: Mate this one allowing Dany +2 also, I Dont want like that, I just want to check Dany - 1 to Dany - 9

Comment: @Dany Alves: you need to understand regular expressions. Then the accepted solution can easily be modified to check for Dany - 1 to Dany - 9